# how to pass javascript variable into liquid markup?

Tags: javascript, variables, liquid

I have a value from JavaScript:

```
  var customerID = document.getElementById("CustomerID").value;
```

Now I want query the firstName, lastName from module data, based on that customerID variable.

```
    {module_data resource="customers" version="v3" fields="id,firstName,lastName,titleType,customerTypeId,ratingTypeId" skip="0" limit="10" order="lastName" collection="selected-data"}  
    {% for item in selected-data.items %}
    {% if item.id == 10393092%}
     document.getElementById("CAT_Custom_15").setAttribute("value","{{item.titleType.label}}") ;
     document.getElementById("CAT_Custom_14").setAttribute("value","{{item.firstName}}");                        
     document.getElementById("CAT_Custom_4").setAttribute("value","{{item.lastName}}");
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

How should I write the where condition?
Whne I assign instant value that 10393092 in my code above. It is working fine. but I need assign the variable equal to item.id(like item.id == customerID). Anyone can help? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible. Liquid generates a static page, which is then stored on your web server. When a user navigates to your site, the pre-generated page is sent to them. Then the JavaScript in it may execute. At this point, it is impossible to do anything in Liquid. You should be looking for a pure JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do that. Reason is liquid is processed at server side and you will be fetching the content from the browser DOM using

```
var customerID = document.getElementById("CustomerID").value;
```

When the page loads, the content from server (for `module_data`) have already processed and after that the DOM elements will load resulting in no data passed to liquid `if else` condition.
At the moment there is no way to send javascript data to the server for `module_data`.